# Rendering an array of objects in React but it says objects cant be child elements

Tags: reactjs, fetch-api

I am storing the response from an API in an array called Products. This array stores the objects returned. I am displaying the title property of the objects in a div. But getting objects cant be child elements in React error. What should I do?
Also, I have tried rendering the products title (eg: Products[0].title)  but even this doesn't work. But this is not an object. So why doesn't this work?

**Code on React:**

```
const App = () => {
  
  const [Elec,setElec] = useState("");
  const [Jewe,setJewe] = useState("");
  const [MJ,setMJ] = useState("");
  const [WMJ,setWMJ] = useState("");
  const [Products,setProducts] = useState([]);
  
  const fetcher = (e) => {
      fetch('https://fakestoreapi.com/products/categories')
      .then(res=>res.json())
      .then(json=>{
        console.log(json);
        setElec(json[0]);
        setJewe(json[1]);
        setMJ(json[2]);
        setWMJ(json[3]);
        console.log(setElec);
        
      })
    }

  const jewelleryproducts = () =>{
    fetch('https://fakestoreapi.com/products/category/jewelery')
            .then(res=>res.json())
            .then(json=>{console.log(json);
              setProducts(json);
              console.log(Products);
        
            })
  }  

    return(
      <> 
     <Head>
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/general.css"></link>
     </Head>
      <div>
      <div className="searchbardiv">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search"></input>
        <a href="./jewellery"><img src="./images/cart.png" typ></img></a>
        <a href="./electronics"><img src="./images/avatar.jpg"></img></a>
        
        </div>
      <div className="categories">
        <div> <button
        type="submit"
        onClick={e => {fetcher()}}
        >Show all categories</button></div>
        <ol>
        <li><a>{MJ}</a> </li>
        <li><a>{WMJ}</a></li>
        <li><a>{Elec}</a> </li>
        <li><button type="submit" onClick={ e => {jewelleryproducts()}}>{Jewe}</button></li>
        </ol>
      </div>
      <div className="jewelleryproducts">
          <div>{Products[0]}</div>
          <div>{Products[1]}</div>
          <div>{Products[2]}</div>
          <div>{Products[3]}</div>
          </div>


      </div>
      </>
    )
    }
export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this

```js
  <Select>
            {list.map((el) => (
              <Option key={el.code} value={=el.code}>
                {el.name}
              </Option>
            ))}
          </Select>
```

Comment: The above snippet works. thank u

Answer (score 0):

You need to [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over the array and define what you should be displayed for every iteration.

**Example:**

```
<div className="jewelleryproducts">
   {Products.map(product => (
      <div>{product}</div>
   )}
</div>
```

This also prevents the code duplication.

**Note:** this example is based on the assumption that each `product` is a string.
If that's not the case, then it should be adjusted accordingly.

Comment: no each product is an object

Comment: You did not specify this. Either way, it is still the same concept, except instead of `{product}`, it becomes `{product.name}` / `{product.id}` etc.. And so on for every field you want to render.

Comment: I got the point. it is working now. thank u